# Best way to create & destroy a thing exactly once in React? (Are unused setters from usestate okay?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-usememo

I have a giant game object which is attached to a canvas on render. I want to create it exactly once when the component is created, and not delete it until the component is destroyed.

(If the game is periodically created and destroyed then users will lose their game states. Let's say I don't want to edit the game to put storage in a `Context` or `Redux` or something, and want to leave the game as is..)

I see at least three ways to do this:

```
function Game1() {
    const [world, _] = useState(createWorld) // unused setter
    useEffect(() => world.destroy, [])
    const attachCanvas = useCallback(canvas => world.start(canvas))
    return <canvas ref={attachCanvas}/>
}

function Game2() {
    const [world, setWorld] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        const newWorld = createWorld()
        setWorld(newWorld)
        return newWorld.destroy
    }, []) // <- adding setWorld and newWorld dependencies can create loops
    const attachCanvas = useCallback(canvas => world.start(canvas))
    return <canvas ref={attachCanvas}/>
}

function Game3() {
    // Works but docs say that a memo may be called twice if the engine feels like it
    const world = useMemo(createWorld, []) 
    ...
}
```

Is there anything wrong with `Game1`? Is there a fourth, better way to create and destroy state exactly once?

Comment: Game1 creates world and then useEffect immediately destroys it.

Comment: No it doesn't, it returns the destroy method.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is fine.

However, sometimes it's just easier to write a Class based React component. You can use the class constructor to init your game world as a Class member property, and then use the componentWillUnmount lifecycle hook to destroy it.

```js
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    this.world = createWorld();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.world.start(canvasRef.current);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.world.destroy();
  }

  render() {
    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine to create a permanent state once and never update it. You don't need to deconstruct the setter either, so your code could be `const [world] = useState(createWorld);`

Answer (score 1):

One last option I found is writing a custom hook or using a pre-existing one, like `ahooks`'s [useCreation](https://ahooks.js.org/hooks/advanced/use-creation/) which also allows dependencies. A simple custom hook might look like:

```
function useOnce(factory, makeCleanup) {
    const [x] = useState(factory)
    useEffect(makeCleanup(x), [])
    return x
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way to Create and destroy variables in React hooks.

```
function Game1(props) {
  const [world, setWorld] = useState("");
  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate
  useEffect(() => {
    setWorld("hello"); // Now world will be equals to "hello"
  });
  // Similar to componentWillUnmount
  useEffect(() => {
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      setWorld(""); // Reset state here
    }
  });
}
```